# Transit via UK from US to Ghana (same day flight/US visa): Do I need a UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, transit

I am a Ghanaian student studying in the US. I am scheduled to be travelling to Ghana via the UK. I have a 3 hour layover in the airport and then my flight for Ghana departs. I have a valid F-1 visa for the US so do I need to apply for a transit visa for the UK?

Comment: Ghana is a DATV country (meaning you generally need a visa) but it seems you might qualify for a “transit without visa” concession since you are returning from the US with a valid US visa, see the [UK Border Agency website](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-transit-airside/).

Answer (score 4):

**Short:** A UK transit visa (formally a 'direct airside transit visa or 'DATV) is NOT required in your case as long as all your travel documents and visas as required for the US and Ghana are in order and you complete the transit within 24 hours.

**Longer / Because:**

You will not need to have a DATV to transit UK airspace because you meet the following conditions:

- You are a national of a country covered by the DATV system (Ghana) and
- You are arriving and departing by air

Provided that:

- Your onward flight is confirmed and
- You depart within 24 hours (as planned) and
- You have proper documentation for your destination, including a visa if necessary.
- You must hold a valid entry visa for the USA, and a valid airline ticket for travel via the UK, as part of a journey between the US and Ghana.

The above is obtained from the [UK Border agency site - Do I need a visa to transit airside?](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/transitthroughtheuk/visa-transit-airside/) which is the one that 'Solver' cited.

I get the opposite answer to him after reading:

- 3rd paragraph headed "You can transit the UK airside without a visa if:"
- Pop out list at bottom of page with heading "Nationalities requiring a DATV", which advises that Ghana *IS* one such country  BUT
- this is modified in pop out list at bottom of page headed "Transit without visa' concession - DATV exemptions" - which provides the conditions which I summarised above

---

You also do not need a DATV if the following applies to you:

- You are recognised as stateless under the 1954 UN Convention relating to the Status of Stateless Persons
- You hold a valid travel document issued by the UK government
- You are recognised as stateless under the 1951 UN Refugee Convention and qualify for the DATV exemption under the 'transit without visa' concession - see under 'More information' below.

Comment: Under the exemptions there's a long list titled `Additionally, you must hold:` which might exclude OP and require OP to get a visa.

Comment: The OP said he or she is Ghanaian, why is everybody copying/paraphrasing all the stuff about stateless people?

Comment: @Annoyed Why are you posting complaints about what "everybody is doing" on my answer when it does not apply to me. Yes, I did add a comment about stateless people on the bottom for completeness, but the summary mentions them not and the main answer relates directly to her (presumably) case - having omitted much material that was superfluous to increase clarity. I'd have thought that adding additional as a footnote and clearly separated would be considered a bonus. Apparently not :-).

Comment: @jOHANNES. No. Or, yes, but I've covered it :-). The list that you cite includes "or" after every item - ie you need to satisfy a minimum of 1 of them. The one relevant to Akosua is the very first, requiring her to hold a valid entry visa to the US (in this case) plus a valid airline ticket to Ghana from the US via the UK (in this case). I covered this in my answer in point 4 under "Provided that". |
I suspect that as her journey is US to Ghana, if she was not returning to the US, then the entry visa requirement may not apply, but I included it as the rules do not make the distinction.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon But it does apply to you… Copying the whole content of the website without tailoring it to the question, – including some pretty exotic cases – does not seem very useful.

Comment: @Annoyed - No rudeness intended here - You seem more intent on criticising what I wrote than on reading it. I looked at the specific information provided, went through the page concerned in detail, found the material that I considered applied or may apply given what was said and extracted ONLY the material which I considered relevant. My aim was the standard test of "necessary and sufficient" -> That produced the material down to the line. None of the material was boiler-plate copied unless I considered it directly applied and a lot was amended  as needed. This took a wee while. Then ...

Comment: ... And only then, I  considered what she had said about being a Ghanaian student and decided to add the footnote. This was perhaps slightly biased by my once having met a young woman in Hong Kong who described herself similarly (but from Uganda) but I subsequently found that she was considered stateless as a refugee and was waiting clearance subject to her refugee state being accepted. That was not stated here and is very probably not the case but the footnote makes the answer more useful for others and does no harm as long as the material above is selected to be wholly pertinent - as it is.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Fair enough, I guess we just disagree on what's relevant. For example, in my view, being stateless is really a corner case and something the person would be acutely aware of. Hence my impression that you just “dumped” most of the information available but it's true that unlike the other user, you took the time to present a succinct conclusion and comment on what seemed applicable or not.